# sort elements by path in mesh

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm trying to find a way to sort a mesh order by a path from one end to the other.

Basically the end goal is to use the build modifier to animate a generated ivy branch to grow from one point out (up a pillar), segment by segment. The default order for the ivy branches builds out one full branch at a time (so it grows one branch all the way up and then the next branch up etc.) Is there an easy way to select the right order? Or perhaps a better way to create the animation I'm trying to create?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the use of tool, 'Sort Elements'?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/147139/whats-the-use-of-tool-sort-elements)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73633/animate-branch-growth/73672 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82188/fill-along-the-front-of-a-path-of-an-svg/82200#82200