# Build modifier animation starting from wrong starting point

Tags: animation, modifiers

I have selected the starting point on my Boolean object to reveal the sphere animation. But the animation wont start from that selected point where the cursor is, I have also specified: sort Elements> Cursor  Distance (faces), but still wont start from the selected point.

https://streamable.com/rt0gqa

[image]

Comment: Look into sorting: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/147139/whats-the-use-of-tool-sort-elements/147141#147141 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/191649/how-can-i-sort-vertex-positions-sequentially-indices-in-a-closed-area/191656#191656

Comment: Do I have to sort all these numbers manually? https://ibb.co/mNBGWBw
What is a correct way to achieve what I am after, some other technique maybe?

Comment: You could use the convert trick of robin betts answer with the python 3liner

Comment: Please share this link so I can see, I don't understand what you're referring to.

Comment: I can't properly load the image in your link. I was refering to the robins answer in my second link. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/191783/30849

Comment: Ok thank you for this, I just had a brief peep and and seems intimidating, I've never seen python script before. Ill give it a go tomorrow, thank you for your insight.

Comment: The first sentence of the [linked answer](blender.stackexchange.com/a/191783/30849) is: "Without a script:" (Maybe you looked at another answer?)

Comment: Is there another option I can make it like a revealing mask? the reason why I am using this Build modifier is more masking purposes.

Comment: Maybe this modifier isn't for complicated masking technique I suppose?

Comment: Would you be kind enough to share some screen shots of your method?

Comment: I turns out I was talking rubbish. I am going to try to redeem myself with a [blend](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/8O3Xry0o/). Please take a look.

Comment: thank you kindly for your file, it sure does shed some information regarding my problem. Maybe what the community needs is someone with great knowledge to do a video tutorial and post it on YouTube, so people can be more aware of masking animated complex objects, I scouted the internet to find some info regarding this technique but found nothing helpful.

Comment: That's what this site is for. You can always edit your question to make it more clear, general and concise. And you can add your own answer to document your findings.